# "Edit tags" link is missing; is that a reputation privilege?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, editing, retagging

It used to be that if I hovered over the end of the row of tags I would see an "edit tags" link.  I no longer see this; I'm not sure how long it's been gone, but possibly since graduation.  Is this a reputation privilege?  That seems odd, since I can edit tags freely by editing the post.

I see the link on English (graduated, 10k) and Biblical Hermeneutics (beta, 3k); I do not see it on UX (graduated, 1.9k) or Writers (beta, 1.8k).

Comment: FWIW I still see it, so it's either a very local bug or a privilege thing. I agree though that it is an odd privilege to save for really high up.

Comment: I have noticed that that feature sometimes disappears for me, though I can't reproduce the issue at the moment.

Comment: You have 3k on BH? Nice!

Comment: @HodofHod, thanks.  It's been something of a surprise to me.  (My biggest tags are genesis and hebrew. :-) )

Comment: FWIW, I do not see the link on http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/ , where I have rep of 3387 and the ability to do regular edits. However, the rules could well be different there.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, aha! And I don't see the link on [english.se], where [500 rep points should give me the privilege](http://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) and I have 2823. Same for MSO (500 bar; I've 796; no link).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111145/the-edit-tags-link-available-to-10k-users-is-visible-in-the-review-page-only-a indicates that "edit tags" is only available to 10K+-rep users. I haven't found this documented elsewhere, and I don't understand why this policy is so.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, thanks for finding that!  I wonder why the threshold for getting the link should be much higher than the threshold for being able to edit via another path?

Comment: MonicaCellio, @IsaacMoses, for the reason see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/#comment-45740.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Michael Mrozek](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/26/michael-mrozek), [mmyers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/222/mmyers), and [Shog9](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/3435/shog9) for explaining this to me and linking to [a question on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117624) that explains some more. Here goes:

[500 is the rep needed to edit the tags on a question.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions)
[2000 is the rep needed to edit a question.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit)
10000 is the rep needed for the 'inline tag editor' (i.e. the "edit tags" link that allows you to edit tags without leaving the page), even though that doesn't seem to be documented [at `/privileges`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools)

So below 500, you have an "edit" link that causes your edit to be queued for approval.
[image: (screenshot thereof)]
From 500 to 2000, you have a retag link that saves your revision but isn't 'inline'
[image: (screenshot thereof)]
and an "edit" link that queues your edit.
From 2000 to 10000 you have a regular "edit" link (no queue) but no "retag" link (because you can edit and not just retag) and no 'inline'-retagger link (because you don't have [that privilege](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/#comment-45740) yet)
[image: (screenshot thereof)]
— and above 10000 you have the 'inline' retagger (and no "retag" link).
[image: (screenshot thereof)]

Comment: The fact that this isn't documented at /privileges is a bit of a bug.

Comment: Huh, odd.  Thanks for the research!

Comment: In general, I find it strange to have ease of use features dependent on "reputation points"

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I agree with you completely; for the opposing view, see the answer to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/#comment-45773 (directly beneath it).

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer; just data collection.

Please visit a question on main (any, but not one you've just edited) and check to see if you get the link.  Add your name, mod status if applicable, current reputation, and yes (if you see it) or no (if you don't) to this answer.  Let's see if we can validate or reject a reputation connection.

- MonicaCellio, 6974, no
- IsaacMoses ♦, 12,266, yes
- DoubleAA, 16,171, yes
- msh210 ♦, 21,087, yes

Comment: ^^^ was a valiant effort :)